# Copying Conditional Formatting from Another set of Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a matrix in which each cell is two numbers concatenated together. As a result, I cannot do a conditional formatting heat map on the matrix as excel doesn't have a range of numbers to read cleanly.

The two numbers (in each cell) come from two separate matrices . The second matrix has the numbers I want to be the basis of the conditional format for the main matrix.

Is there a way to copy the condititonal formatting from that sub-matrix overlaid over the main matrix?

Comment: Conditional formatting can be a formatting by formula. Formula can reference to user-defined function. UDF can perform any check you need practically...

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is to change your concatenation formula to =(Concatenate(Range))*1. This should convert the concatenated value to a number allowing the conditional formatting to work.